# Why Can't Mathematica Integrate this?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to integrate Absolute-value functions from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_integrals):
[image]

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Assuming[{x ∈ Reals, a ∈ Reals}, Integrate[Abs[Tan[a x]], x]]
Integrate[Abs[Tan[a*x]], x, Assumptions -> {a, x} ∈ Reals]
Assuming[{x ∈ Reals, a ∈ Reals}, Integrate[Abs[Cot[a x]], x]]
Integrate[Abs[Cot[a*x]], x, Assumptions -> {a, x} ∈ Reals]
Assuming[{x ∈ Reals, a ∈ Reals}, Integrate[Abs[Sec[a x]], x]]
Integrate[Abs[Sec[a*x]], x, Assumptions -> {a, x} ∈ Reals]
Assuming[{x ∈ Reals, a ∈ Reals}, Integrate[Abs[Csc[a x]], x]]
Integrate[Abs[Csc[a*x]], x, Assumptions -> {a, x} ∈ Reals]
```

with **NO** symbolic result?

I have `"10.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)"`

Comment: I confirm, the first example did not return any result on Mma10.3, Win7/64

Comment: This issue may be related to the fact that `Integrate[Tan[a*x], x, GenerateConditions -> True]` generates no conditions.

Comment: `Why Can't Mathematica ... whatever?` kind of questions are typically unanswerable without access to the inner code

Comment: `Integrate` does not fare will with non-analytic functions, and `Abs` is not analytic. Also the Wikidepia article is somewhat lacking in terms of how it actually defines antiderivatives of functions that are at best discontinuously differentiable over R.

Comment: `Integrate[Sqrt[Tan[a*x]^2], x]` works, but that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Don't see why the question is off-topic.  Isn't the answer simply that the integrands contain discontinuities & divergences (as can be seen from, for instance `Plot[Abs[Tan[x]], {x, -Pi, Pi}]`), and that, as is often the case with such integrands, one needs to do the integration piecewise and then infer, from the pieces, the general form? E.g., corresponding to what Plot shows, these work:  `Integrate[Abs[Tan[a x]], x, Assumptions -> -Pi/2 < a x < 0]`  and `Integrate[Abs[Tan[a x]], x, Assumptions -> 0 < a x < Pi/2]` and so on...

Comment: Of course, sometimes MMA is able to handle non-analytic integrands directly, e.g.: `Integrate[Abs[x + Abs[x]^2], x, Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]`

Comment: @theorist. On MMA `11.3` works fine all examples. `Integrate[RealAbs[Tan[a x]], x, 
 Assumptions -> {x \[Element] Reals, a \[Element] Reals}]`.